# Can we define variables in `.tpl` files?

Tags: php, smarty

In general, if we have a Smarty project we assign variables in `.php` file, and use the variables in its corresponding .tpl` file.

such as:

```
$smarty->assign('foo', 'Foo');  // in .php file

{$foo}  // in .tpl file
```

can we define the variables in `.tpl`? and if can, is this recommend? 
and why?

Comment: we can define as herrjeh42 said but it's not recommended, we have to use php for any logic and variable assignment, but sometimes we may need to use it, so we can use it

Comment: There's [documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
{assign var="foo" value="Foo"}
{assign "foo" "Foo"} {* short-hand *}

The value of $foo is Foo.
```

Comment: The value of {$foo} is just Foo when printed

Answer (score 0):

Use in smaartly by calling to `$ss->assign('i', $i);` and in your `.tpl` file you can access it with the `{$i}` notation.